# Not receiving email with PHP form

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to make a simple html form with php to send messages to a specific email. A friend sent me this form but since i'm very noobish in PHP i can't seem to figure out why i'm not receiving any emails...
This is my HTML CODE:

```
<div  class="form">
                    <form id="contactform" action="mailer.php" method="post"> 
                        <p class="contact">NOME</p> 
                        <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Primeiro e último nome" required type="text"> 

                        <p class="contact">EMAIL</p> 
                        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="exemplo@domínio.com" required type="email"> 

                        <p class="contact">MENSAGEM</p> 
                        <textarea rows="6" required placeholder="Escreva aqui a sua mensagem"></textarea> 
                        <br />
                      <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="ENVIAR" type="submit">     
                   </form> 
                </div>
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php
$to      = 'MYEMAIL@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: MYEMAIL@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $name, $subject, $message, "From: MYEMAIL@gmail.com\n");

?>
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your form is wrong:

```
<h2>Feedback Form</h2>
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  From: <input type="text" name="from"><br>
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>
  <?php 
  }
else
  // the user has submitted the form
  {
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["from"]))
    {
    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("webmaster@example.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$name is not a parameter in the mail function. If you are trying to add the persons name somewhere, add it to the subject, message or define it as an additional parameter. Try taking $name out and see if it works without it.

[PHP mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)